# Use single-site install and map entities to subdomains

Tags: url-rewriting, dns

Not sure if this is a pipe-dream, but I am interested in the URL rewriting capabilities (and DNS mapping) of a single-site WordPress install.

Typically in a WordPress MU setup, we'd use [WordPress Mu Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) to map new sites/installs to a domain/CNAME.

What I'd be after is if it's possible to map a single-entity, like a user to a CNAME on the registrar.

For example, let's say we have a bunch of users in a single-site install. Ideally, these users would be accessed via `YOURSITE.COM/johndoe` (using [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) which is an additional question).
Then, on the registrar level, you setup a CNAME that has a value of `us.OURDOMAIN.COM` and point it to the IP address of the site. From there, WordPress is able to determine that `us.OURDOMAIN.COM` should load `YOURSITE.COM/johndoe`.

Any initial thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks as always!

Comment: Zach... why is it always you asking such overly complicated questions? :P Maybe [Christopher Davis article](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api) helps you to get things sorted.

Comment: Ha I know right... who the heck do I think I am?! ;) Appreciate the article, I'll take a gander

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are still interested in this question. I did a sub domain mapping to a custom post type using custom `.htaccess` setting.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain-name\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?store=%1 [L]
```

Using this setting, each sub domain will map to the `store` custom post type. `http://apple.domain-name.com` will be equal to `http://domain-name.com?store=apple` or  `http://domain-name.com/store/apple/` if you are using the pretty permalink.

Note that you will need to modify the pager if you want to map the sub domain to category or custom taxonomy.